# Renaming a field in a type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a type and I would like to create another type from it in which one field is renamed to another. E.g., I have a type like

```
    type A = {
      name: 'A'
      A: number
    }
    
    type B = {
      name: 'B'
      B: number
    }
    
    type Before = A | B
```

and I want to rename the field `name` in `Before` to `name2`.

At first. I thought about something like

```
type After = Omit<Before, 'name'> & { name2: Before['name'] }

const a: After = {
    name2: 'A'
    A: 2
}
```

This is also the answer I saw in some similar question here.

But then I get an error when defining `a`.

```
Type '{ name2: "A"; A: number; }' is not assignable to type 'After'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'A' does not exist in type 'After'.(2322)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a distribution problem, which we can solve one of two ways:

1. With a mapped type
2. By working directly from the source types `A` and `B` directly, it works as expected:

#### Mapped type

We can create a utility type to rename a key:

```typescript
type Rename<ObjectType, FromKey extends PropertyKey, ToKey extends PropertyKey> = {
    [Key in keyof ObjectType as Key extends FromKey ? ToKey : Key]: ObjectType[Key];
}
```

Like `Omit`, that will be distributed across the `A | B` union, giving us the result we want:

```typescript
type After = Rename<Before, "name", "name2">;

const a: After = {
    name2: "A",
    A: 2,
};

const b: After = {
    name2: "B",
    B: 2,
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oDsCGBbCAXFAEQzEDcaGMRmArrgEYQBOlAvpSqJFAEIJkVdDnxFifCsP60GzNik4pu4aHwgAzAPYtoiOAB9+XHtABKEURAA8AeUYArCAGNgAFVUAaKADEWW3ABpCBAoCAAPYEsAEwBnKAAFf0gWUGCQbzctdLDImPikrRS0kIA+QVQMKABtHIBLTCgAaxCtDSh7J1cPXmx4nIiozDjffyCQqAB+KCyconSAXSJOl3dVWpCFjhNVWA0olkELK2t1bV1vYitiS6sAJmJSrmctTFjgKGwiGH3WCul7uIyJ5pDQoHcQUoUC83h9GN9fodEJUMICSJIQVU+EQIYpyEA)

#### From the source types

But if you didn't really need `Before`, you could just define `After` directly from `A` and `B` using `Omit` as you've shown:

```typescript
type A = {
    name: "A";
    A: number;
};

type B = {
    name: "B";
    B: number;
};

type Before = A | B;

type After =
    | (Omit<A, "name"> & { name2: A["name"] })
    | (Omit<B, "name"> & { name2: B["name"] });

const a: After = {
    name2: "A",
    A: 2,
};

const b: After = {
    name2: "B",
    B: 2,
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oDsCGBbCAXFAEQzEDcaGMRmArrgEYQBOlAvpSqJFAEIJkVdDnxFifCsP60GzNik4pu4aHwgAzAPYtoiOAB9+XHtBgbgrBNKMAKAPK4AlsAA8MADQlREYgD4oADJkLDwIACYiGABtYh9iAF0odgBKGygHZzc+Lziw-yCQn0j+WPik1K4AYy1MAGdgKGwoiytEVAxQ-BLSYg9pGihw-qUUGvrGxhbLFkEOjGLxSX7OviJhxUogA)